# iowait for while/sleep bash script on debian/64

Tags: bash, io

I'm running a mysql-DB server (debian/squeeze/64) with 48GB RAM and 8TB disk, lots of inserts and quite a few CPU-intensive background processes.

Since some of these processes kept dying I used a simple bash-watchdog to restart them, which worked, but produced a lot of iowait. I simplified the problem down to:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do sleep 1; done
```

which still produces iowait of up to 90% for the bash(!)-process (as seen on iotop). there's no disk read or write displayed and the test-script really is just this one line.

Note that everything's working fine and the server is still perfectly responsive. I'm just curious to know what's going on.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: And what about global iowait? Try `dstat -ldcymsn` while you run the script, is there actually a lot more IO usage? Otherwise my guess is that the IO wait is due to `sleep` being permanently thrown out of the fs cache then reread again from disk at each invocation (sleep is not a builtin!).

Comment: global iowait is at around 2-5% (but i suppose the bash-io-wait will count into that, so that's probably the biggest portion of the global wait)

Comment: disk read/write also isn't all that much, most of the time it's zero, somtimes it peaks at 20MB/s for 1-2 seconds, not more. mem usage says 3.5G free, 24G cache so basically there should be enough room for the sleep command

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce your results, possible it's a bug.

I tested on Arch(vm) and Ubuntu(physical), running a while with a sleep of one second resulted in minimal IO and essentially no IOwait.

Comment: the problem only occurs on my production db machine - on a machine with low load (not many db inserts) the bash loop doesn't cause io wait. only in the presence of (mostly cached) io does the loop cause extra io wait